# Multiple JavaScript actions in one link

Tags: javascript, html

I'm using this [Tab Content Script](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex17/tabcontent.htm) from dynamicdrive.com. I'm not sure how much of the code I need to include here, if any, but all the functional code is found on that page.

In short, it's a nice script that creates tabbed navigation. What I'm trying to do is make a single link select two tabs. Separately, they'd look like this:

```
<a href="javascript: menu1.expandit(0)">Select First Tab in Menu 1</a>
<a href="javascript: menu2.expandit(2)">Select Third Tab in Menu 2</a>
```

Can I combine those href statements somehow?

Comment: Wow DD is still around? That takes me back...anyways, you might consider trying out Bootstrap or even jQuery + jQuery UI for some more modern solutions.

Comment: DD IS still around, barely! :) I would like to use something more modern, but the menus are already set up using this method, and there are a lot of them. So mostly just for the sake of time, I'd rather use figure out how to get these links to do what I want them to instead of redoing essentially everything.

Comment: What do you mean selecting two tabs? you can view only one it a time?!

Comment: @A.Meshu I have multiple menus on screen at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way is:

Adding multiple event listeners to one element.

```
<a id="button">Click</a>
```

JS:

```
document.GetElementById("button").addEventListener("click", myFunction1);
document.GetElementById("button").addEventListener("click", myFunction2);
document.GetElementById("button").addEventListener("click", myFunction3);


    function myFunction1() {
        document.getElementById("id1");
    }

    function myFunction2() {
        document.getElementById("id2");
    }

    function myFunction3() {
        document.getElementById("id3");
    }
```

I used document.getElementById as an example. You can put anything.

Comment: Both of your answers worked for me, but I liked how this one is constructed a little better. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Functions inside of a function.

```
<a id="button" onclick="myfunction">Click</a>
```

JS:

```
    function myfunction() {

    function myFunction1() {
        document.getElementById("id1");
    }

    function myFunction2() {
        document.getElementById("id2");
    }

    function myFunction3() {
        document.getElementById("id3");
    }
}
```

I used document.getElementById as an example. You can put anything.

Answer (score 0):

Use a callback on onclick like so:

```
<a href="" onClick=(()=> {menu.expandit(0); menu.expandit(2);})>
```

Comment: This isn't working. It displays the link as this: `{menu.expandit(0); menu.expandit(2);})>link name`